# Finding joint distribuion of $X,Y$ given joint moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, moment-generating-functions

Let $M_{X,Y}(t_1,t_2) = {t_1^2+t_2^2\over 2}$ be the joint moment generating function of $X,Y$. Is it possible to find the joint density function of $X,Y$?

I´m having a really difficult time in this problem. I don´t know hot to compute the joint density. I would really appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The MGF is usually defined by $M_(X_1,X_2)(t_1,t_2)=Ee^{t_1X_1+t_2X_2}$. With this definition we have  $M_(X_1,X_2)(0,0)=1$ so your function is not a  MGF.

I suppose you want to consider $M_(X_1,X_2)(t_1,t_2)=Et_1^{X_1}t_2^{X_2}$. I will answer the question taking this as the definition.

Solution based on guess work: $(X,Y)$ takes just two values $(0,2)$  and$(2,0)$ with probability $\frac 1 2 $ each.

Comment: That would yield $\frac12(e^{t_1}+e^{t_2})$.

Comment: @Math1000 Please take a look at my answer now.

Comment: Ah, good point on recognizing that we must have $M_{X_1,X_2}(0,0)=1$ for a valid moment generating function. That explains why I couldn't find anything using $\texttt{InverseMellinTransform[t^2,t,x]}$ in Mathematica.